# cannot bind angular js to controller member

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this controller

```
'use strict';

var opsToolControllers = angular.module('opsToolControllers');

opsToolControllers.controller('payoutCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'Util', 'User', 'Payout', function ($scope, $location, Util, User, Payout) {

    $scope.refundReasons = ["1 -- No show compensation", "2 -- Bonus not paid"];
    $scope.userId = null;
    $scope.totalPay = null;

    function init() {
        $scope.status = null;
        $scope.payouts = null;
        $scope.pending = null;
        $scope.showPayoutsInfo = false;
        $scope.showPendingInfo = false;
    };

    function successCallBack(response) {
        $scope.opStatus = Util.parseError('OK');
        $scope.transactionId = "";
        Util.stopProcessIndication();
    };

    function errorCallBack(response) {
        $scope.status = Util.parseError(response);
        Util.stopProcessIndication();
    };


    $scope.payDriver = function (userId, totalPay, chosenReason) {
        Payout.payDriver(userId, totalPay, chosenReason, successCallBack, errorCallBack())
    };

    $scope.userId = $location.search().userId;
    if ($scope.userId) {
        $scope.getUserPayouts($scope.userId);
    }

    $scope.validateTotal = function(obj, total) {
        $scope.totalPay = 150;

        $scope.inputNum.value = parseInt($scope.slider.value);
    };

}]);
```

and this html

```
    <input type="number" id="input_total" class="form-control" ng-model="$scope.totalPay" id="totalPay" required ng-change="validateTotal(this, totalPay)">


    <select ng-options="reason for reason in refundReasons" required ng-model="chosenReason">
        <option value="">Select refund reason</option>
    </select>
<br>

<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="payDriver(userId, totalPay, chosenReason)">Pay driver</button>

</p>
```

what am i missing as the `<input>` doesn't do two way binding with the `$scope.totalPay`

I mean not when I call `payDriver(...)` and not when the validator override the `$scope.totalPay`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. In your controller declare your totalPay variable like this.

```
$scope.total = {};
$scope.total.totalPay = null;
```

Then in your html

```
<input type="number" id="input_total" class="form-control" ng-model="total.totalPay" id="totalPay" required ng-change="validateTotal(this, totalPay)">
```

Comment: Umm did you even try the solution before downvoting it ?

Comment: Read up on this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482/8814332

TLDR : If you want your two way binded variables to work in the expected manner, you need to have two dots in their name.

Answer (score 1):

Juse use **`totalPay`**

```
 <input type="number" id="input_total" class="form-control" ng-model="totalPay" id="totalPay" required ng-change="validateTotal(this, totalPay)">
```

Comment: it didn't help `$scope.totalPay = 150;` in the validator doesn't effects the ui

Comment: This is right, you shouldn't use '$scope' reference in your view.

Comment: @Sajeetharan no errors, but `Risalat Zaman` worked for me. why is it?

Comment: when you are using a ng-model it should be on a object